# Custom List Form works fine in Infopath but gets stuck when deployed

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, external-list

I have a custom list form for whenever I add a new item to a custom list. This form connects to an external sharepoint list that has 3000 records.

When you type a client ID it will connect to the list and get that user's personal information. The form works great in infopath 2010 in preview mode, and I can succesfully upload it and deploy to my site, the problem is when I open the form in the site, and insert the user ID, it will get stuck in "Sending Data to the Server".

Has anyone experienced this before?
How can I fix this? I've been trying to get this to work for days now.

Logs dont show anything relevant, and Infopath brought the information almost instantly.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I've been dealing with this for days and it is driving me crazy. My form will suddenly stop working and I'll have to roll back hours worth of work for no apparent reason....